# Parseval Relation for Dilated Function on Integers

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}.$ If necessary assume that the support of $f$ is finite, and that $\mid f\mid$ is bounded. Define the fourier transform $$\hat{f}:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ by
$$\hat{f}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} f(n)~e^{2i \pi n t}.$$

Parseval states that
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mid f(n) \mid^2 = \int_0^1 \mid\hat{f}(t) \mid^2 \,dt
$$
holds. Now let $v$ be a positive integer $\geq 2,$ and let
$$
f_v(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc} 
f(n/v), & \quad\mathrm{if}\quad & v|n,\\
 & & \\
0 & & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
What is the Parseval relationship for this function?

Also define, with $v$ as before, the "sampled" function
$$
g_v(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc} 
f(n), & \quad\mathrm{if}\quad & v|n,\\
 & & \\
0 & & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
What is the Parseval relationship for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in mathoverflow [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321597/averaged-parseval-relation-for-sampling-a-function-on-integers) where you can go for the details.

Let
$$
f_v(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc} 
f(n), & \quad\mathrm{if}\quad & v|n,\\
 & & \\
0 & & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Let $f=f_1$ for simplicity's sake. Then

$$
\sum_{v=1}^m \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \mid f_v(n) \mid^2
\geq \left( \ln m-\frac{m}{N}\right) \int_0^1 \mid\widehat{f(t)} \mid^2 \,dt.
$$